# Eliminating array rows that do not meet a matching criterion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider an array, M, made up of **pairs of elements**. (I've used spaces to emphasize that we will be dealing with element PAIRS).  The actual arrays will have a large number of rows, and 4,6,8 or 10 columns.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,3,  2,1,  4,2,  3,3],
              [3,5,  6,9,  5,1,  3,4],
              [1,3,  2,4,  3,4,  7,2],
              [4,5,  1,2,  2,1,  2,3],
              [6,4,  4,1,  6,1,  4,7],
              [6,7,  7,6,  9,7,  6,2],
              [5,3,  1,5,  3,3,  3,3]])
```

**PROBLEM:**  I want to eliminate rows from M having an element pair that has **no common elements** with any of the other pairs in that row.

In array M, the **2nd row** and the **4th row** should be eliminated.  Here's why:
**2nd row:**  the pair (6,9)  has no common element with (3,5), (5,1), or (3,4)
**4th row:**  the pair (4,5)  has no common element with (1,2), (2,1), or (2,3)

I'm sure there's a nice broadcasting solution, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broadcasting solution. Hope it's self-explained:

```
a = M.reshape(M.shape[0],-1,2)

mask = ~np.eye(a.shape[1], dtype=bool)[...,None]

is_valid = (((a[...,None,:]==a[:,None,...])&mask).any(axis=(-1,-2))
            |((a[...,None,:]==a[:,None,:,::-1])&mask).any(axis=(-1,-2))
           ).all(-1)

M[is_valid]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 7, 2],
       [6, 4, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7],
       [6, 7, 7, 6, 9, 7, 6, 2],
       [5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: A variation of this problem was posted on Dec 1 by user109387.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this would be the following -

```
M = np.array([[1,3,  2,1,  4,2,  3,3],
              [3,5,  6,9,  5,1,  3,4],
              [1,3,  2,4,  3,4,  7,2],
              [4,5,  1,2,  2,1,  2,3],
              [6,4,  4,1,  6,1,  4,7],
              [6,7,  7,6,  9,7,  6,2],
              [5,3,  1,5,  3,3,  3,3]])

MM = M.reshape(M.shape[0],-1,2)

matches_M = np.any(MM[:,:,None,:,None] == MM[:,None,:,None,:], axis=(-1,-2))
mask = ~np.eye(MM.shape[1], dtype=bool)[None,:]

is_valid = np.all(np.any(matches_M&mask, axis=-1), axis=-1)
M[is_valid]
```

```
array([[1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 7, 2],
       [6, 4, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7],
       [6, 7, 7, 6, 9, 7, 6, 2],
       [5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Nice.  I'll do some time tests to compare the methods.

Comment: Mine would be slightly slower, since I am extracting the 'match' matrix (7,3,3) so that it can solve more than just this test, but also the test here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65099156/eliminating-array-rows-that-fail-to-meet-two-conditions

Comment: simplified the code a little taking inspiration from @Quang Hoang's more efficient answer