# Eliminating array rows that fail to meet two conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider arrays m and n.  Both have identical shapes.   m and n always have an even number of columns, and I have added spaces to emphasize that each array row is made up of **PAIRS** of elements.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[5,3,  6,7,  3,8],
              [5,4,  5,1,  4,5],
              [5,4,  2,4,  4,6],
              [2,2,  2,3,  8,5],
              [2,7,  8,7,  1,2],
              [2,7,  8,7,  3,2],
              [2,7,  8,7,  4,2]]) 

n = np.array([[1,3,  6,7,  1,12],
              [2,4,  2,9,  4,9],
              [1,5,  5,12, 9,1],
              [5,4,  5,6,  9,5],
              [5,4,  1,4,  1,5],
              [5,4,  1,7,  9,5],
              [5,4,  1,5  4,11]])
```

My overall objective is to **eliminate rows from m that fail to meet two TEST conditions:**

**TEST 1:**  we keep rows of m only if **every pair had a common element with some other pair in the row.**  This has already been answered very capably by Quang Hoang on Nov 13, 2020, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64814379/11188140 ).   I include it here because the code will be helpful with TEST 2 to follow.

Using this code, the 1st row of m is rejected because pair (6,7) has no common element in the other row pairs.  The 4th row of m also is rejected because its last pair has no common element in the other row pairs.
The earlier code, that works perfectly, and its output are as follows:

```
a = m.reshape(m.shape[0],-1,2)
mask = ~np.eye(a.shape[1], dtype=bool)[...,None]

is_valid = (((a[...,None,:]==a[:,None,...])&mask).any(axis=(-1,-2))
            |((a[...,None,:]==a[:,None,:,::-1])&mask).any(axis=(-1,-2))
           ).all(-1)

m[is_valid]
```

The output, m, is:

```
              [[5,4,  5,1,  4,5],
               [5,4,  2,4,  4,6],
               [2,7,  8,7,  1,2],
               [2,7,  8,7,  3,2],
               [2,7,  8,7,  4,2]]
```

**TEST 2:**  we keep rows of m only if **the row in array n (ie: same index) has the SAME PAIR MATCHINGS as in m.**  An n row may have 'extra' pair matchings as well, but it  **MUST** include the pair matchings that m has.

Three examples make this clear:

```
a) 5th row of m and n:  '[2,7,  8,7,  1,2]' and '[5,4,  1,4,  1,5]'
   In m, the 1st & 2nd pairs share an element, and the 1st and & 3rd pairs share an element.
   n has both of these matchings, so **TEST 2 PASSES**, and we keep this m row. 
   The fact that 2nd & 3rd pairs of n also share an element is immaterial.                                                                          
                                                                                                
b) 6th row of m and n:  '[2,7,  8,7,  3,2]' and '[5,4,  1,7,  9,5]'
   In m, the 1st & 2nd pairs share an element, and the 1st & 3rd pairs share an element.
   n DOES NOT have BOTH of these matchings, so **TEST 2 FAILS**.  The row may be eliminated from m (and from n too if that's needed)

c) 3rd row of m and n:  '[5,4,  2,4,  4,6]' and '[1,5,  5,12, 9,1]'
   In m, the 1st & 2nd pairs share an element, the 2nd & 3rd pairs share an element, and the 1st & 3rd pairs share an element.
   n lacks the 2nd & 3rd pair sharing that m has, so **TEST 2 FAILS**.  The row may be eliminated from m (and from n too if that's needed)
```

The final output, m, after passing both tests, is:

```
              [[5,4,  5,1,  4,5],
               [2,7,  8,7,  1,2],
               [2,7,  8,7,  4,2]]
```

Comment: Any reason why 2nd row of m `[5,4,  5,1,  4,5]` does come in the final output? It satisfies the first condition, and the second row of n `[2,4,  2,9,  4,9]` has the same matches as well.

Comment: Yes, but that is precisely why the 2nd row of m is kept.   It passes TEST1 because each pair has a common element with some other pair in the m row, and it passes TEST 2 because all of the matched pairs in the m row are also found in the n row.  So, we keep this row in m because it passed both conditions.

Comment: ya got it after a while, do check my solution. I am adding an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution for the above 2 tests you mention. I have modified the code a bit for test1 as well so that it flows nicely into test2.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[5,3,  6,7,  3,7],
              [5,4,  5,1,  4,5],
              [5,4,  2,4,  4,6],
              [2,2,  2,3,  8,5],
              [2,7,  8,7,  1,2],
              [2,7,  8,7,  3,2],
              [2,7,  8,7,  4,2]]) 

n = np.array([[1,3,  6,7,  1,12],
              [2,4,  2,9,  4,9],
              [1,5,  5,12, 9,1],
              [5,4,  5,6,  9,5],
              [5,4,  1,4,  1,5],
              [5,4,  1,7,  9,5],
              [5,4,  1,5,  4,11]])


mm = m.reshape(m.shape[0],-1,2) #(7,3,2)
nn = n.reshape(m.shape[0],-1,2) #(7,3,2)

#broadcast((7,3,1,2,1), (7,1,3,1,2)) -> (7,3,3,2,2) -> (7,3,3)
matches_m = np.any(mm[:,:,None,:,None] == mm[:,None,:,None,:], axis=(-1,-2))  #(7,3,3)
matches_n = np.any(nn[:,:,None,:,None] == nn[:,None,:,None,:], axis=(-1,-2))  #(7,3,3)

mask = ~np.eye(mm.shape[1], dtype=bool)[None,:]  #(1,3,3)

is_valid1 = np.all(np.any(matches_m&mask, axis=-1), axis=-1)  #(7,)
is_valid2 = np.all(~(matches_m^matches_n)|matches_n, axis=(-1,-2)) #(7,)

m[is_valid1 & is_valid2]
```

```
array([[5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5],
       [2, 7, 8, 7, 1, 2],
       [2, 7, 8, 7, 4, 2]])
```

Explanation -

**TEST 1**

1. First step is to reshape n and m to `(7,3,2)` so that we can broadcast over `axis=1`
2. Next we need to get a comparison between the elements of the last axis for the cross product of elements for each row. So the expected output would be `(7 rows, 3X3 cross product between elements)`.
3. But for the comparison, I would also have to broadcast over the last axis (2x2). Meaning I would need a `(7,3,3,2,2)`. This can be done by doing broadcasting over 2 arrays of `(7,3,1,2,1)` and `(7,1,3,1,2)`.
4. Finally an any() over the last 2 axes will give you a `(7,3,3)` where, for each of the 7 rows, you are comparing each element to the other, and returning True if any of them has a common element. `THIS IS ALSO THE ARRAY THAT CONTAINS THE MATCHES AND WILL BE IMPORTANT FOR TEST2!`
5. Next, since the same element comparison will always give True, you want to ignore the diagonals, so create a mask for it.
6. Using the mask, get which of the elements have at least 1 match with other elements except itself, and that solves TEST1.

**TEST 2**

1. Apply the same first 4 steps to get the matches matrix `(7,3,3)` for n.
2. Here, `any match that exists in m MUST exist in n`, but `any match that exists in n is not needed in m`. The required logic is -

```
a = np.array([True, False, True, False])
b = np.array([True, True, False, False])

~(a^b)|b
#array([ True,  True, False,  True])
```

3. Applying this over the 2 `(7,3,3)` matches, if even a single false exists in the respective `(3,3)`, it indicates that matches between pairs in m are not reflecting in n. So you get `False` there. This over `axis = -1, -2` results in a `(7,)`
4. This gives you the TEST2.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Elegant solution!  I'm a relative newcomer to numpy, so the explanatory notes are really helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I would encourage you to break down run each step in the code for better understanding as some of the things I did are not that easy to explain.

Comment: EDIT: Just fixed a bug, where I had accidentally hardcoded a dimension.

Comment: The 'is_valid2 ' line in the solution has a flaw, and I'd like to know if a fix is possible.

Comment: could you post the error? I am getting the expected solution for the test case you have provided. Can you give me another test case where it fails? I could see and fix it then

Comment: The 'is_valid2 ' line in the solution has a flaw, and I'd like to know if a fix is possible.  Here's the problem:  the expression  'matches_n[matches_m].reshape(mm.shape[0],-1)' presumes that 'matches_n[matches_m]' is divisible by mm.shape[0].   This is the case with the question as shown above because 'matches_n[matches_m]' has 49 elements and mm.shape[0] = 7.   Usually, though, this reshaping is not possible.   By changing the most upper-right digit of m from 8 to 7,  'matches_n[matches_m]' now has 51 elements which 7 won't divide.   Any ideas?

Comment: let me check, great bug finding.

Comment: Yes.  here is the error message when the upper right digit of m changes from 8 to 7.  ---> 32 is_valid2 = np.all(matches_n[matches_m].reshape(mm.shape[0],-1), axis=-1) #(7,)
     33 
     34 m[is_valid1 & is_valid2]

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51 into shape (7,newaxis)

Comment: yea i see that. its just a matter of fixing the operation between matches_m and matches_n. let me see what i can do

Comment: I can't replicate this right now, but there were also cases where the 1st rows of m and n , say, contributed 5 elements to  'matches_n[matches_m]', the 2nd rows contributed 9 elements, and all the others contributed 7 elements.   Bottom line,  the cardinality of  'matches_n[matches_m]' = 49, so divisible by 7 even though elements from the 2nd rows were attributed to the 1st.

Comment: yea, i found the logic needed. The issue is that i it needs a one way gate. Basically i need to implement `~(a^b)|a` logic to get the matches that exist in a vs b. The boolean indexing logic is flawed. give me some time to fix it.

Comment: This is the core logic that needs to be fixed - `any match that exists in m MUST exist in n, but any match that exists in n is not needed in m.`

Comment: I have updated my solution, can you check and confirm if it works for your usecases and doesnt bug out? Also, updated the explaination for test2

Comment: Hey, Akshay - that works beautifully on a set of input arrays, including multiple instances of 4, 6, and 8 column m and n arrays.   I appreciate your time and expertise.  Best of all, I find the detailed comments , as a fairly new coder, to be helpful indeed.

Comment: glad to help, this was a good problem to solve.